# Could somebody help me read these ACF and PACF plots?

Tags: forecasting, autocorrelation, autoregressive, box-jenkins

So, I have this time series that I have already forecasted using an ARMA model, but I am new to this and am therefore not at all sure whether or not I did this (somewhat) correctly.
I got the best results when differentiating the series twice, but I am not sure if it was really the right way to go.

What would your inputs be when looking at the provided ACFs and PACFs? They all are from the series. Without differences, once differentiated and twice differentiated.

[image: ACF - original time series] [image: PAFC - original time series]

[image: ACF - once differentiated] [image: PACF - once differentiated]

[image: ACF - twice differentiated] [image: PAFC - twice differentiated]

Answer (score 1):

Your ACF (of the undifferenced series) appears to be exponentially decaying, and your PACF has a peak at lag 1 and no other significant peaks. [This suggests an AR(1) process.](http://otexts.org/fpp2/sec-nonseasonalarima.html)

I recommend the entire [textbook by Hyndman and Athanasopoulos](http://otexts.org/fpp2/). A more modern approach to ARIMA order selection relies on [information criteria](http://otexts.org/fpp2/estimation-and-order-selection.html). You may also want to browse through earlier threads in the [box-jenkins](/questions/tagged/box-jenkins) tag, which contain many other examples of interpretation of ACF/PACF plots.